# NULL value in specific column results in field duplication when extracting mysql record set

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have the following mySQL query:

```
$query = sprintf(
    "SELECT a.A,
            a.B,
            ...,
            a.C,
    FROM a
    WHERE a.A = %s
    ORDER by a.A;",
          implode(" OR a.A = ", $_SESSION['values']));
```

for some records, *B* has a value, and for others, *B* is NULL

I extract the query with the following PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);//fetches data stored within each row
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column => $field){
        if($field == $...){
            ...
        }
        elseif($field == $C){
            echo"<td>
                    <input type='text' name='C+[]' value='$C'>
                </td>";         
        }
    echo "</tr>"
}
```

In the resulting html table, records containing **not null** *B* fields are presented accurately, while records with **null** *B* fields incur a duplication of field *C*. This offset occurs at the beginning of the record, pushing the final field in the record outside the table boundaries.

I think I've narrowed down the problem to the extract() function, as r_print readouts of every other variable in the script returns the accurate field names and values. But, running print_r on  $row after extract() provides an identical printout to other variables in the script.

What are some possible ways I can stop the duplication of field *C* from occurring?
Happy to provide more information upon request.

Comment: Have you heard of `GROUP BY` clause???

Comment: I have. Should I be using it?

Comment: Only if you want to get correct results :)

Comment: Hi @bodi, I just tried replacing ORDER BY with GROUP BY in the MySQL query, but unfortunately I am getting the exact same result. Thank you for the feedback though. Do you have any other ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: Also dont use extract($row) like that. You have a perfectly good array returned so use it. Why generate multiple scalar variables and duplicate everything???

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, I'm happy to experiment with alternatives to extract($row). Do you have any suggestions I could try out?